# How to add real data in OMNeT UDP packet?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am working on IoT sensor scenario in INET sensornetwork in wireless showcase. How I can add real sensor data eg. temperature values (23 21 25 26 23 13) in packets and then draw graph with received data values?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to define your own [message class](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part4/#44-defining-our-message-class).

Comment: Ok. Where I can find some better instructions? 
Thank you

Comment: Please note that with the new Packet API included in INET 4.x, this no longer holds. See: https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/developers-guide/ch-packets.html